# Get All Revisions / Track Changes From an Excel Document Via VB Macro

Tags: vba, excel

There is scarce information online regarding extracting a list of all revisions from an excel document programmatically, or telling the difference between an excel 
sheet that has unaccepted changes and one that does not

I have tried to do some digging through the xml etc.

However i was wondering if there was any functionality similar to words revisions.count functionality in order to extract this information. Specifically through visual basic if possible.

Comment: I have had to do some unholy things involving python and xml but i've finally got there :)

Answer (score 0):

@dipl0: Tracking / managing parameters in Excel has never been as easy in Excel as it is in Word. I found no other way than using VBA along with some old Excel tricks.

Things you should do:

- Compile a list of whatever issues your organization judges important to have tracked
- Try to address as much traceable issues with standard Excel properties (BuiltInDocumentProperties) but have no fear to create your own CustomDocumentProperties
- Prepare Excel VBA code to get a property (either BuiltIn or Custom) value & assign it to a named range (once it is there, you can use it wherever you want, as usual)
- Prepare Excel VBA form & code to manage those properties (either BuiltIn or Custom) and update the named ranges as needed
- Treat your changes log as a subset of those activities, so prepare another Excel VBA form & related code to manage a revision changes log and update the main revision accordingly

The underlying VBA code to that all is quite long, but the essence is there. I deeply hope this helps you plan your own activities and fill in the blanks.

Kind regards

Comment: I have had to do some unholy things involving python and xml but i've finally got there :)